# Loading and setting values of json in scala

Tags: scala, cucumber, bdd

I am new to scala and cucumber. I have following json file in the resources of project.

```
{
  "town": {
    "address": {
      "Dates": [
        {
          "startDate": ""
        }
      ],
      "condtion": {
        "includeAll": [
          {
            "type": "",
            "id": "",
            "details": [
              {
                "destination": ""
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "includeAny": [
            {
            "type": "",
            "id": "",
            "details": [
              {
                "value": ""
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
      "FinalId": "N9"
    }
  }
}
```

Field are kept empty in this file. In my feature file I have following info in examples:

```
Given:...
When: ...
Then: ...

Examples:
| includeAll                                                    | includeAny |
|typeValue;idValue;destination,typeValue1;idValue1;destination1 | typeValue2;idValue2;destination2,typeValue3;idValue4;destination4
```

values of field are separated by delimeter ";" and particular combination is separated by another  delimeter ",". I may many combinations of typeValue,idValue, destinationValue to in my feature file separated by "," and I need to load that empty json and set them in my json and store json in a varaible or file. includeAny values may or may not be present but includeAll will always be there. In case if includeAny values are not specified, I don't want to include "includeAny" in my final json. How can I do that?

Comment: Indicate which libraries are used

Comment: for  json work generally I use spray json.  But any library  for  me will suffice